# Wrapping text with a span, using waitForKeyElements, is killing the styling?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am using Greasemonkey and `waitForKeyElements()` to change some text in a webpage.

Here is an example of a single jNode element.

```
<div class="Ov-h Mx-a">
    <div>
        <div class="Grid-bind-end">
            <div class="ysf-player-name Nowrap Grid-u Relative Lh-xs Ta-start">
                <a class="Nowrap" href="http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/players/7206" target="sports">H. Miller</a> <span class="Fz-xxs">Pit - TE</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="Grid-bind-end">
            <span class="ysf-player-status F-injury Fz-xxs Grid-u Lh-xs"></span>

            <div class="ysf-player-detail Nowrap Grid-u Fz-xxs Lh-xs Ta-start">
                <span class="ysf-game-status"><a class="F-reset" href="http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/pittsburgh-steelers-new-england-patriots-20150910017/" onclick="pop(this)" target="sports">Thu 5:30 pm @ NE</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to change `Thu 5:30 pm @ NE` to `Thu 5:30 pm @ < span class="color">NE - [rank]</span>` (Note that [rank] is a variable I have)

Here is what I have tried

```
jNode.text((jNode.text().replace("NE","<span class='color'>NE - [rank]</span>")))
```

But this makes the element lose it's styling.

Comment: Okay, this kind of wrapping -- of *text*, in a single node -- is one of the rare-ish places it is okay to use jQuery's `.html()` in a userscript.  There are "purer" DOM methods but as long as the replaced node has no children or event handlers, the drawbacks are minimal and the `.html()` is usually clearer and simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you take only the text ("H. Miller Pit - TE" etc) of the entire node tree in `<div class="Ov-h Mx-a">` and use it as the new contents discarding all existing html layout inside the DIV.

The correct method generally is to change the contents *only of the relevant elements* to avoid recreation of sibling elements (so that event listeners attached with `addEventListener` or `on` keep working on them) and use `.html()` (since you're adding html):

```
var link = jNode.find(".F-reset");
link.html(link.html().replace("NE","<span class='color'>NE - [rank]</span>"));
```